# Excel: Split data of simgle column into multiple column column-wise VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some data in excel as given below:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
```

When I split it into multiple columns using ASAP utilities. It splits the data column wise. Like suppose if i want to split it into 5 columns, it will be in row-wise fashion like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23
```

But, I want to split it column-wise like this:

```
1   6   11  16  20
2   7   12  17  21
3   8   13  18  22
4   9   14  19  23
5   10  15
```

I used the code given [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2244-excel-split-long-column-into-multiple-columns.html), but it asks for number of rows. I want it to ask number of columns and then split the data just like ASAP Utilities does.

All positive suggestions are welcomed...

Comment: Wait, is there a typo here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, a little user friendly,

When you run this macro, `vba` shows a text box in which you can enter the number of columns you want to split your data into.

[image]

When you enter `5`, and click `Ok`,

[image]

and your code is here,

```
Sub transpose()
Dim col As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
col = InputBox("Enter number of columns")
col = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row / col
col = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(col, 0)
j = 1
k = 3
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(j, k) = Cells(i, 1)
    j = j + 1
    If j > col Then
        j = 1
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This code dynamically splits the column based on your input. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, not fully tested yet, but a start.

```
Sub t()

Dim xDimension As Integer
Dim lngLoopCount As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngPresentation As Long

xDimension = 5
lngPresentation = 1

lngLastRow = Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row

For lngLoopCount = 1 To lngLastRow Step xDimension
    Range("c1").Offset(lngPresentation, 0).Resize(1, xDimension).Value = _
                Application.Transpose(Range("a1").Offset(lngLoopCount - 1, 0).Resize(xDimension, 1).Value)
    lngPresentation = lngPresentation + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: it is arranging in row-wise fashion. I want it to arrange it in column-wise. as you can see in the second split that i have given

Comment: same geometry, look at `offset` and `resize` to see how to switch.

Comment: I didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

Please try this piece of code,

```
Function SPLITARR(ByRef v() As Variant, MaxRow As Integer) As Variant
  Dim ArraySize As Integer
  Dim MaxCols As Integer
  Dim NewArray() As Variant
  Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer

  ArraySize = (UBound(v(), 1) - LBound(v(), 1)) + 1
  MaxCols = ArraySize \ MaxRow

  If ArraySize Mod MaxRow > 0 Then MaxCols = MaxCols + 1
  ReDim NewArray(LBound(v(), 1) To MaxRow, 1 To MaxCols)
  For x = LBound(v(), 1) To UBound(v(), 1)
    y = x Mod MaxRow
    If y = 0 Then y = MaxRow
    z = x \ MaxRow
    If x Mod MaxRow = 0 Then z = z - 1
    NewArray(y, z + 1) = v(x, 1)
  Next
  SPLITARR = NewArray()
End Function
```

and should be called like,

```
Sub caller()
Dim a() As Variant
a() = Range("A1",Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
a() = SPLITARR(a(), 5) '<~ change this to your needs
ActiveCell.Resize(UBound(a(), 1), UBound(a(), 2)).Value = a()
End Sub
```

It gives an output like

[image: called 1]

[image: called 2]

Comment: I want to call it directly without using event

Comment: Call it directly as `Button1_Click()` you mean?

Comment: no, that program should execute directly when i click on Run

Comment: I will edit this answer and assume that you have those numbers lined up in column A.

Comment: sure, that will be great

Comment: Done, so paste both of the codes in the same module and I hope it works for you.

Comment: I think you've got rows and columns mixed up. @V15HM4Y wants it to be split over 5 rows, not 5 columns (example - change your function to split over 7 instead of 5 and it returns 4 columns)

Comment: And I just did the same. 5 columns not 5 rows***

Comment: Added sample picture. @Tom - am I really that mistaken?

Comment: Reread question. Specifically states @V15HM4Y wants it to ask for number of columns not rows

Comment: @Tom - I stand corrected. \* hides himself of shame \*.

Answer (score 0):

This will split your range over 5 columns in the order that you want. It will need you to update the `With` statement to the relevant sheet that you're looking at and the split can be changed by altering the `NoCols` variable to how ever many columns you desire in your output.

```
Public Sub SplitRange()
    Dim arr As Variant, tmp As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim NoCols As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c

    ' Change this to how many columns you want
    NoCols = 5

    ' Change to your sheet
    With Sheet6
        .Range(.Columns(4), .Columns(20)).Clear
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
        tmp = rng.Value2

        ReDim arr(1 To WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(UBound(tmp) / NoCols, 0), 1 To NoCols)

        i = 1: j = 1
        For Each c In tmp
            If i > WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(UBound(tmp) / NoCols, 0) Then j = j + 1: i = 1
                arr(i, j) = c
            i = i + 1
        Next c

        With .Cells(1, 4)
            Range(.Offset(0, 0), .Offset(UBound(arr, 1) - 1, UBound(arr, 2) - 1)) = arr
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```